# Google Cloud Speech Error - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

Running the following code and trying to thread a batch of calls through google cloud-speech using python I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range.

I cannot figure out where it is falling down, it works is small  batches of 2 threads and 10 files. But when I scale beyond that I get the following error. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
def transcribe_c_gcs(gcs_uri):
  from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

  client = speech.SpeechClient()

  audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
  config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    language_code='en-US',
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True
    )

  operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)


  reading = operation.result(timeout=90000)

  transcript_dict = {'Word':[], 'start_time': [], 'end_time':[]}

  for result in reading.results:
      alternative = result.alternatives[0]


      for word_info in alternative.words:
          word = word_info.word
          start_time = word_info.start_time
          end_time = word_info.end_time
          transcript_dict['Word'].append(word)
          transcript_dict['start_time'].append(
          start_time.seconds + start_time.nanos * 1e-9)
          transcript_dict['end_time'].append(
          end_time.seconds + end_time.nanos * 1e-9)


  comp = pd.DataFrame(transcript_dict)

  comp['id'] = [gcs_uri.split('_')[2] for _ in range(len(comp.index))]

  comp['version'] = [gcs_uri.split('_')[3] for _ in range(len(comp.index))]

return comp

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    results = executor.map(transcribe_c_gcs, filelist)

asyncres = pd.concat(results, axis=0)

asyncres.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: 1) Include the error stack trace. 2) Before dereferencing an array check that it has values and the length. 3) Check that your index does not exceed the array length.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting? results = executor.map(transcribe_c_gcs, filelist),,,,, filelist is not defined ???